# Writing a response handler in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8

My service calls a downstream service, which returns a `ResponseEntity<MyBodyClass> response`. My service needs to react differently based on different properties of `response`

For example if `response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` and `response.getBody().code == 1`, the service should do some action "A", but if for the same status code the `response.getBody().id == 1`, then it should do "B". Another example is if `response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK` and `response.getBody() != null`, service should do "C".

I know this can be done with a bunch of if statements, but is there a better design pattern?

Comment: You can use the strategy pattern, creating a different action class for each result. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strategy-pattern-set-1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement the rules as a chain of responsibility :

```
ruleFoo -> ruleBar -> ruleFooBar -> ....
```

The chain has to be ordered according to the rule precedence and each element of the chain (the rule here) is processed to detect a match. As soon as a rule matches the rule performs the suitable action and the chain process is stopped.

Here a very simple implementation that takes advantage of java 8 stream (that is a little different of the original GOF pattern but I Like it because that is lighter to implement).

```
public interface ResponseRule {        
    boolean match(Response response);                  
    void performAction();                          
}

public class RuleFoo implements ReponseRule {

    public boolean match(Response response){
       return response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST && response.getBody().code == 1;
    }

    public void performAction(){
       // do the action
    }
}

public class RuleBar implements AbstractReponseRule {

    public boolean match(Response response){
       return response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST && response.getBody() != null;
    }

    public void performAction(){
       // do the action
    }
}
```

And how use them :

```
Response response = ...;
List<ResponseRule> rules = new ArrayList<>();
rules.add(new RuleFoo(), new RuleBar());

rules.stream()
     .filter(rule -> rule.match(response))
     .findFirst()
     .ifPresent(ResponseRule::performAction);
```

Note that if rules execution could be accumulated, that would require a small change :

```
rules.stream()
     .filter(rule -> rule.match(response))
     .forEachOrdered(ResponseRule::performAction);
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual technique is to use a "handler" class. You first need an interface:

```
interface ResponseHandler {
    // The order in which handlers are called
    int getPriority();
    // return true of the response is handled by this handler
    boolean handle(ResponseEntity<MyBodyClass> response);
}
```

Then create some implementations:

```
class BadRequestHandler implements ResponseHandler {
    public int getPriority() {
        return 1;
    }
    public boolean handle(ResponseEntity<MyBodyClass> response) {
        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST 
            && response.getBody().code == 1) {
            // do stuff to handle the request
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you need a List of them and you loop over the list trying each handler in turn until one returns true.

```
List<ResponseHandler> responseHandlers;
// add response handler implementations to the list and sort it.
for (int i = 0; i < responseHandlers.size() 
        && !responseHandlers.get(i).handle(response); i++);
```

Before using the list you should sort it on `getPriority`. The easiest way to do that is to implement Comparable in the object as well. See [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property).

This technique will not be as efficient as just writing a lot of if statements (since you can probably factor the conditions to remove common sub-conditions) but it does offer the flexibility to plug-in new handlers more easily and the code may be more readable.